# error C2228: left of '.GetX' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, class

Below is Point.h:

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point();
    Point(int, int);
    void SetX(int);
    void SetY(int);
    int GetX() const;
    int GetY() const;
private:
    int x, y;
};
```

In another class "Employee", there is a method whose parameter is a Point object and I want to call its member method GetX() and GetY(), but it failed with error "C2228: left of '.GetX' must have class/struct/union" and "C2228: left of '.GetY' must have class/struct/union", why would this happen?

Employee.h

```
class Employee
{
public:
    Employee(string str, Point &p)
    {
        name = str;
        point = p;
    }
    void SetCoordinates(Point &p)
    {
        point.SetX(p.GetX()); //**error here**
        point.SetY(p.GetY()); //**error here**
    }
private:
    string name;
    Point point;
};
```

Comment: Where is p defined?

Comment: Because "p" is undefined.

Comment: `str` is also undefined.

Comment: Did you copy this code without reading it? Function parameters need types and identifiers. This should have been explained in the first weeks of the class.

Answer (score 1):

In your implementations, the parameters you use need names, not just types:

```
class Employee
{
public:
    Employee(string str, Point p)
    {
        name = str;
        point = p;
    }
    void SetCoordinates(Point &p)
    {
        point.SetX(p.GetX());
        point.SetY(p.GetY());
    }
private:
    string name;
    Point point;
};
```